# $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0)=0$ there exists $g\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)=xg(x)$

Tags: general-topology, distribution-theory

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0)=0$ I want to show that there exists $g\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)=xg(x)$. For this I tried to consider the following function
$$ g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x} \qquad g(0)=f'(0)$$
But I cannot show that $g\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$. Does this function check the hypotheses?

Comment: $g$ is smooth around $0$, this follows from $g(x) = \int_0^1 f'(xt)dt$

Comment: why $g\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What does $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ mean?

Comment: @reuns It means smooth compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 It means smooth on the whole real line and vanishing outside of a finite interval $[-N,N]$, as "compact" and "support" probably don't have a clear meaning for the OP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(x)}{x} & (x\neq 0), \\
f'(0) & (x=0). \\
\end{cases}
$$
This function is obviously continuous for $x\neq 0.$ At $x=0$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(0+x)-f(0)}{x} = f'(0) = g(0)
$$
so $g$ is also continuous there. Also, $\operatorname{supp}g \subseteq \operatorname{supp}f$ so $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R}).$

Now, as **reuns** suggests, we can notice that
$$
g(x) = \int_0^1 f'(xt) \, dt.
$$
(Remember to check both the case $x\neq 0$ and $x=0$.)

Derivatives of $g$ are given by
$$
g^{(k)}(x) = \int_0^1 t^k f^{(k+1)}(xt) \, dt
$$
which by construction are defined for all $x$ and all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ since $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}).$ Thus $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}).$

So, since $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ we have $g\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}).$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ vanishes outside $[a,b]$, so does $g$. As a quotient of smooth functions, $g$ is smooth for $x\neq0$. At $x=0$ you have
$$
f(x)=f(0)+f’(0)x+\frac 1 {2}f’’(0)x^2+\dots=f’(0)x+\frac 1{2}f”(0)x^2+o(x^2)
$$
by the local Taylor formula. Actually you can expand up to any order $n$ with remainder $o(x^n)$. Dividing by $x$ you get
$$
g(x)=f’(0)+\frac 1 {2}f’’(0)x+o(x)
$$
(Or the corresponding expansion to order $n$) which is infinitely differentiable at zero with $g(0)=f’(0)$ etc.

The reason is: suppose the above relation holds ($n=1$). Setting $x=0$ you obtain $g(0)=f’(0)$. Then, dividing throughout by $x$ and taking the limit as $x\to 0$ you obtain, by definition of “little o” and of derivative
$$
g’(0)=f’’(0)/2.
$$
Using the corresponding expansion with $n=2$, and the previous values and dividing throughout by $x^2$ you get in the limit
$$
g’’(0)=f’’’(0)/3
$$
Etc.

Comment: The assumption is that $f$ is smooth, not real-analytic. You don't necessarily have $f(x) = \sum a_n x^n$

Comment: I am only using the local form, which is correct as soon as all the derivatives exist at zero. No analiticity is needed

Comment: Will edit it to make it more clear

Comment: Okay, now the main problem with this is that it's not clear a priori that the error term is smooth after dividing by $x$ (without analyticity).

Comment: That is not needed. If a function can be represented in that form for all $n$, it’s derivatives of all orders exist at zero. A posteriori, the remainder is smooth as well

Comment: Okay, but you would need a proof of that for a full solution. It's certainly not obvious to me.

Comment: Just added some explanation. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: I am following your solution up to the point you try to compute $g''(0)$. To compute $g''(0)$, you need to compute the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g'(x)-g'(0)}{x}$, which in turn requires knowledge of $g'(x)$ for $x \neq 0$. Your solution tells us nothing about $g'(x)$ for $x \neq 0$. 

I presume what you're trying to do is use $g(x)=f'(0)+\frac{1}{2!}xf''(0) + \frac{1}{3!} x^2 f'''(0) + o(x^2)$, which by your prior work is precisely $g(x)=g(0)+xg'(0) + \frac{1}{3!} x^2 f'''(0) + o(x^2)$. Call this equation $(1)$.

Comment: There is no obvious way to deduce $g''(0)=1/3! f'''(0)$ from $(1)$. A naive approach which you might have had in mind is differentiating $(1)$ so that the left hand side is $g'(x)$. This is not clear since $o(\cdot)$ relations are in general badly behaved under the differentiation operator.

Furthermore, note that the relation $h(x)=p_2(x) + o(x^2)$ for some differentiable $h$, and $p_2$ a quadratic polynomial, does not imply $h$ is twice-differentiable, as $x \mapsto x^{10} \sin x^{-20}$ shows.

Comment: Going to sleep now. Will get back to you tomorrow. I see your point …

Comment: Your objection is right. It is a bit odd, however, that from the fact that $g$ minus its linearization is an infinitesimal of order $\ge 2$ at a point does not follow the existence of $g’’(0)$ as your example shows. An alternative way that works is to find $g’(x)$ in terms of $f$ and it’s derivatives for $x\neq 0$ and find the limit defining $g”(0)$ directly by expanding $f$ and $f’$ at zero according to local expansion. That gives the value $g”(0)=f’’’(0)/3$ (not $f’’’(0)/3!$). It is possible to get a general formula for $g^n$ outside of zero and conclude that $g^n(0)=f^{n+1}(0)/(n+1)$.